# How can I get the right string when capturing http post response in Electron?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, electron

I was using `webContents.debugger` to capture http post response according to the offical mannual, but it seems that the JSON string in the response was decoded a wrong charset.

The response header did not give the exactly charset, so I guess chrome-devtools decoded it in a wrong charset (maybe iso-8859-1).

I tried this to convert the string:

`let content = new Buffer(e.Content, "binary").toString();`

Sometimes it really works! But it fails to deal with some Chinese characters such as "啊" cause the buffer was not correct in the utf8 form.

`"你好" => E4 BD A0 E5 A5 BD, √
"啊" => e5 22 60, ×    //correct code is E5 95 8A`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/encoding to convert encoding to utf-8

Comment: It works just the same as `new Buffer(e.Content, "binary").toString()`.